# Carnival/Muses short story?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, ray-bradbury

Anyone know of a short story that takes place in a carnival with the Muses as central characters?  They each use their particular talents to compete for the attention of a handsome new member of the troupe. The unlikeliest wins.  I remember it as a Bradbury tale, but haven’t been able to find it.

Comment: Hi welcome to SF&F!  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: All of the Muses?  Were they mentioned by name?  It would be amusing to have the muse of epic poetry mentioned by name in the context of a circus. :)

Comment: It was a long time ago, definitely in a book, not a magazine, and yes, all of the Muses were mentioned by some version of their Greek names . A truly excellent short story and I would love to find it again.

Comment: @DavidW [calliope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calliope_(music)) :-)